# insert empty spaces between two strings in a label

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I want to insert two stings in a label, one in the right side and other in the left side of label. But how to find the number of the empty spaces between two strings?

Thank you in advance,

Mohsen

Comment: @ WorkSmarter Winform.

Comment: If the two strings are trimmed of whitespace, is it still necessary to find the number of empty spaces between the two words?

Comment: In other words, I want to align two strings. One in the right and one in the left side of the label. So, I need the empty spaces to fill the space between the two strings.

Comment: There isn't a trivial solution to this. For this to work you need to figure out the maximum number of characters that will fit into a label. The problem is, unless you use a fixed-width font that number will depend on which characters are in the words. If you do intend to do this, then set the font to something like "Courier New" and start typing until the string is too long to fit. You will then know how many characters will fit into your label, and your problem is now solvable.

Comment: @Setsu Yes. I've tested it, but I forget to use a fixed-width font. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can accomplish this.

```
        const string value1 = "Hello";
        const string value2 = "World";
        int labelLength = 20;  //This is the size of the box. Adjust to fit your needs.
        if ((value1.Length + value1.Length) > labelLength)  //Prevents ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        {
          label1.Text = "Error - Label is too small";
        }else {
            var ExtraspaceLength = labelLength - (value1.Length + value1.Length);
            value1withspace = value1.PadRight(ExtraspaceLength);         
        }
        label1.Text = String.Format("{0}{1}", value1withspace, value2);
```

Comment: Notice the use of the quotes in the String.Format.  This is much more flexible then using "+" for concatenation purposes.

Comment: He's not trying to insert _a_ space, he's trying to insert enough spaces so that word 1 is on the left of the label and word 2 is on the right of the label.

Comment: This does not insert one string on the left and other on the right of the label.

Comment: How large is the label and the words in question?  If we knew how much space we need to use, we could then create a loop which will add the extra space between the words.

Comment: label width is 850, and strings have different length. I get them from a datagridview.

Comment: You get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException from `value1.PadRight()` if the lengths of value1 and value2 combined exceed `labelLength`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to pad spaces and limiting yourself to a fixed-width font, you can achieve the same effect using 2 labels instead. Create a panel and inside it put 2 labels, one docked to the left and the other docked to the right; leave auto-size to true for the labels. The labels will automatically expand to fit the string contents and stay docked to their respective sides.

Of course, if the strings get too long one of the labels will start to overwrite the other, but you'd have this problem anyways if you used just 1 label.